# Possible to calculate a double sum in python using list comprehensions to replace both for-loops?

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I have a double sum which reads basically

sum = exp( x^2 + y^2 )

Of course, I could simply use two nested `for` loops but that tends to be time consuming for large numbers. I can use one list comprehension to replace the inner `for` loop, see here:

```
import numpy as np

N_x      = 100
N_y      = 100

# straight forward way
result_1 = .0
for x in xrange(N_x):
    for y in xrange(N_y):
        result_1 += np.exp( (float(x)/N_x)**2 + ( (float(y)/N_y)**2 )

# using one list comprehension
result_2 = .0
for x in xrange(N_x):
    inner_loop = [ np.exp( (float(y)/N_y)**2 ) for y in range(N_y) ]
    result_2  += np.exp( (float(x)/N_x)**2 ) * sum(inner_loop)
```

But how to replace the outer `for` loop as well with a list comprehension (which I expect to be faster), any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = sum(np.exp(x**2 + y**2) for x in range(N_x) for y in range(N_y))
```

Comment: well, that was fast and easy :)

Comment: `result == result_1`--> `False`

Comment: @MikeMüller I've simplified the argument to `np.exp`. The purpose of the answer was to illustrate how you can write two loops in a single line expression.

Comment: @SilverSlash indeed, although I realize now that this might not be the most efficient way...

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you do it the numpy way... without for loops:

```
x = np.arange(N_x)
y = np.arange(N_y)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
result = np.sum(np.exp((xx/N_x)**2 + (yy/N_y)**2))
```

Comment: I was just saying that the OP question asks at first for computing the sum = exp(x^2 + y^2), but the code they want to modify does not actually compute this sum, it does more ...

Comment: coming to think about it, I guess the op equation  is actually consistent with code, I was just confused...

Comment: yeah, it makes a lot of sense to get rid of loops completely

Comment: wow, that is way faster, thanks! (And, yes, the actual code is doing more).

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there. The full sum can be written as the product of two 1D sums, i.e. `(sum exp x^2) * (sum exp y^2)`:

```
>>> import numpy as np                      
>>>                       
>>> N_x = N_y = 100                                      
>>> 
# brute force                         
>>> result_1 = .0
>>> for x in xrange(N_x):
...     for y in xrange(N_y):
...         result_1 += np.exp( (float(x)/N_x)**2 + (float(y)/N_y)**2 )
... 
>>> result_1
21144.232143358553
>>> 
# single product method
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 
>>> x, y = np.arange(N_x) / N_x, np.arange(N_y) / N_y
>>> np.exp(x*x).sum() * np.exp(y*y).sum()
21144.232143358469
```

My guess is this you can even do with list comp and beat the brute force numpy method:

```
>> rx, ry = 1.0 / (N_x*N_x), 1.0 / (N_y*N_y)
>>> sum([np.exp(rx*x*x) for x in xrange(N_x)]) * sum([np.exp(ry*y*y) for y in xrange(N_y)])
21144.232143358469
```

Indeed, timings done in Python3 because I don't know how to use `timeit` in Python2:

```
>>> from timeit import repeat
>>> 
>>> kwds = dict(globals=globals(), number=100)
>>> 
# single product - list comp
>>> repeat('sum(np.exp(rx*x*x) for x in range(N_x)) * sum(np.exp(ry*y*y) for y in range(N_y))', **kwds)
[0.0166887859813869, 0.016465034103021026, 0.016357041895389557]
>>>
# numpy brute force
>>> repeat('np.exp(np.add.outer(x*x, y*y)).sum()', **kwds)
[0.07063774298876524, 0.0348161740694195, 0.02283189189620316]
```

Obviously, numpy single product is even faster

```
>>> repeat('np.exp(x*x).sum() * np.exp(y*y).sum()', **kwds)
[0.0031406711786985397, 0.0031003099866211414, 0.0031157969497144222]
```

Comment: Surely, your code is faster than others. In my computer, [Paul Panzer] 33.4 µs ± 454 ns per loop, [Gerges Dib] 430 µs ± 5.33 µs per loop, [SilverSlash] 18.5 ms ± 343 µs per loop. All codes are faster than the original one.

Comment: @ChoF Thanks for the timings!